# Transforming wide table with proportions to table with proportions AND confidence intervals

Tags: r, data-analysis

So the current table I have looks likes below:

| Edu Level | North | South | East |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .10 | .0002 | .77 |
| 2 | .004 | .0034 | .3498 |
| 3 | .150 | .357 | .548 |

I formed this table by just taking the proportion of people who had the outcome interest in each group.

This is the code I used to make that table. First I had and expanded table:

```
EduLevel_prop <- dta %>%
  filter(!is.na(Diab))%>%
  filter(!is.na(edulevel)) %>%
  group_by(edulevel, region_name) %>%
  count(Diab) %>%
  mutate(perc = prop.table(n))
```

Then I condensed with it with the following code (this is the code for the table above):

```
wide_EduLevelprop <- EduLevel_prop %>%
  filter(Diab==1)%>%
  select(-n)%>%
  spread(region_name,perc)
```

--

I want to transform the table such that the proportion is in the context of a 95% CI. I put the example of row one in the table below.

| Edu Level | North | South | East |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 95% CI | 95% CI | 95% CI | 95% CI |
| 1 | .10 (0.09-.12) | .0002 (0.001-0.0003) | .77 (0.69-0.82) |

Comment: There's missing information, whitout the sample size we cannot compute the standard erros and without them the CI's.

Comment: my expanded table has sample size. Would I have to manually enter the equation?

Comment: Still no sample size shown (the number of observations in each educational level) and the proportions (North/South/East) do not add up to 1.0. Is there a West?

Comment: You can extract CI's from `prop.test` but you will still need the sample size.

Comment: @sam.cold I highly recommend using a reproducible working example, but have submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The below code produces some data similar to your own, estimates the proportions and confidence intervals, and then produces a table where the proportion point estimate and interval are in the same cell.

## Generate example data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)

# Generate example data
N <- 100
df <- tibble(edu = sample(1:3, N, replace = TRUE), 
       region = sample(c("north","south"), N, replace = TRUE),
       outcome = sample(0:1, N, replace = TRUE))

df %>% head(10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>      edu region outcome
#>    <int> <chr>    <int>
#>  1     3 north        1
#>  2     3 south        1
#>  3     3 south        0
#>  4     2 north        0
#>  5     3 north        1
#>  6     2 north        0
#>  7     2 south        0
#>  8     2 north        1
#>  9     3 south        1
#> 10     1 south        0
```

## Define a helper function `prop.test.info()`

```r
# Function that takes a 1-row data.frame, conducts a one-group test, and
# extracts inferential quantities in a data.frame
prop.test.info <- function(df_row) {
  # Conduct one-sample t-test
  result <- df_row %>%
    prop.test(
      x = .$successes,
      p = .$h0,
      n = .$sample_size,
      alternative = "two.sided",
      conf.level = 0.95
    )
  
  # Return CIs in a data.frame
  data.frame(
    ci_low = result$conf.int[1],
    ci_high =  result$conf.int[2],
    prop = result$estimate
  )
}
```

## Estimate proportions and wrangle into `data.frame`

```r
# Calculate sample sizes and cumulative successes
prop_df <- df %>% group_by(edu, region) %>%
  summarize(
    sample_size = n(),
    successes = sum(outcome)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# Add column for null hypothesis of 0.5
prop_df <- prop_df %>% mutate(h0 = 0.5, id = row_number()) 

# Conduct tests, add inferential quantities, round values
out <- prop_df %>%
  split(.$id) %>%
  map( ~ prop.test.info(.x) %>%
         bind_cols(.x)) %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ round(.x, 2)))
```

## Create cell values

```r
# Add combine CI and point estimate character variable, drop all variables
# not needed for table
tabvars <- out %>%
  mutate(est = paste0(prop, " (", ci_low, " - ", ci_high, ")")) %>%
  select(edu, region, est)
```

## Produce table

```r
  tabvars %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = region, values_from = est)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>     edu north              south             
#>   <dbl> <chr>              <chr>             
#> 1     1 0.31 (0.12 - 0.59) 0.41 (0.19 - 0.67)
#> 2     2 0.36 (0.12 - 0.68) 0.43 (0.23 - 0.66)
#> 3     3 0.59 (0.33 - 0.81) 0.56 (0.31 - 0.78)
```